# Get date from file name

Tags: bash

I'm looking for a command or a simple procedure to get the date from the filename. My file name could have multiple date formats.

Eg:

```
Filename                       Format          Output
filename_2016-01-01        filename_%Y-%m-%d   2016-01-01
2016-01-01_filename        %Y-%m-%d_filename   2016-01-01
20160101-filename          %Y%m%d_filename     2016-01-01
1451606400-filename        %s-filename         2016-01-01
```

I'm looking for some procedure say if I specify my "Format" it will return date from that format as output. I'm not worried about format of output. I'm not expecting a huge script. Please let me know if any such functionality already exists.

If there is not other procedure, I'm planning to build one.

Comment: So it is not the time a file was created, rather a subset of the actual filename you want to return? Is it to be stored in a file? Output on screen? Give some pseudo-wanted output.

Comment: Yes. Date from file name. I'll update the output..

Comment: Is the rest of the filename always known? For example, if it is always "Filename<datestuff>" or "<datestuff>_filename" or "<datestuff>-filename", can't you just strip away the known part?

Comment: These are just the requirements. Where is your code?

Comment: @hek2mgl I just wanted to know if there is any simple procedure.. Kind of Yes or No..

Comment: @mattias There could be multiple formats. Maybe I could try your clue.

Comment: @Prashanth I'm not aware of an existing command which could achieve that.

Comment: @hek2mgl Oh.. Thanks. I'll try to strip the file name.

Answer (score 3):

Bash has variable dereferencing modification syntax that can handle some of what you want:

```
$ f=filename_2016-01-01
$ echo ${f#*_}
2016-01-01

$ f=2016-01-01_filename
$ echo ${f%_*}
2016-01-01

$ f=20160101-filename
$ echo ${f%-*}
20160101

$ f=1451606400-filename
$ echo ${f%-*}
1451606400
```